# JQuery Hide / Show Div Before Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What i would like, i click on a link, and a div before this shows or hides, ive tried .prev() and .before() but i do not think i am using them correctly. The code is only part of it, the same code is repeated using owl carousel.

What is happening is all the classes are showing it, not just the 1 item.

So when i click on the showMore button, i want only the previous class: moreInfo to show / hide.

```js
$('.showMore').click(function() {
  var information = $('.moreInfo');
  if (information.is(":hidden")) {
    information.slideDown("slow");
  } else {
    information.slideUp("slow");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <span> 
    <img src="owl1.jpg">       
    <p class="title">Owl</p> 
    <div class="moreInfo">
      <div class="bio">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut feugiat urna arcu, vel molestie nunc commodo non. Nullam vestibulum odio vitae fermentum rutrum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="youtube">
        <iframe width="560" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/n_dZNLr2cME?rel=0&hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning showMore"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
    </div>
  </span> 
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go up one to the `button` DIV and then go to the previous DIV to reach the corresponding `moreInfo` DIV.

```
var information = $(this).closest(".buttons").prev(".moreInfo");
```

Here's the whole updated code:

```js
$('.showMore').click(function() {
  var information = $(this).closest(".buttons").prev(".moreInfo");
  if (information.is(":hidden")) {
    information.slideDown("slow");
    $(this).find("i").text("Show less");
  } else {
    information.slideUp("slow");
    $(this).find("i").text("Show more");
  }
});
```

```css
.moreInfo {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <span> 
    <p class="title">Owl</p> 
    <div class="moreInfo">
      <div class="bio">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut feugiat urna arcu, vel molestie nunc commodo non. Nullam vestibulum odio vitae fermentum rutrum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="youtube">
        <iframe width="560" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/n_dZNLr2cME?rel=0&hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning showMore"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down">Show more</i></a>
    </div>
  </span> 
</div>
```